# With FilePond, How can I include the input name in labelIdle?

Tags: jquery, filepond

Instead of generic text for the filepond button, I want to add the input field name into the text.

Something like the following, but `$(this).attr('name')` returns `undefined`

```
        labelIdle: '<span class="filepond--label-action"> Choose Image </span> for ' + $(this).attr('name'),

})

<input type="file" name="MyInputFieldName" accept="image/*" class="filepond-image">
```

I am trying to make it say `Choose Image for MyInputFieldName`